# How to stop make (in makefile) after "No such file or directory" error?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So, most of the times I'm testing if every include is correct on a given C/C++ code, I have a makefile with a gcc/g++ call with proper -I option for searching headers on specific directories (like every program) when I'm **compiling** sources to headers.

However, if the included directory is not correct and an undefined header appears (e.g. foo.h has #include  and was not found), the gcc/g++ will just spit a bunch of errors for every include I have of that foo.h header for all other sources I'm compiling afterwards (and I'm already using -Werror -Wfatal-errors to make gcc/g++ to stop).

So, my question is simple: how can I tell makefile stop after the first error of the type "No such file or directory" it finds? It is really annoying it continue to compile sources and sources, giving me hundreds of errors just for a repeated error I already understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably continues because you told it to. See the following two options of GNU make:

```
-k, --keep-going          Keep going when some targets can't be made.
-S, --no-keep-going, --stop
                          Turns off -k.
```

Comment: is `-k` the default in some distributions? I've never had that behaviour with mine.

Comment: @stefan: I doubt it, but you can set an environment variable (`MAKEFLAGS`) or on some systems via a global initialization file. Keep in mind the variable could be inherited.

Answer (score 3):

Put the header files into a variable and use that variable as a dependency. The following snippet will not build anything until the specified headers exist.

```
HEADERS=test.h other.h /usr/include/special.h

all: $(HEADERS) $(BINPROGS)

[... all other rules go here as usual ...]

*.h:
    echo found $@
```

The ".h:" simply prints out each header that is found before any building even starts. The makefile itself stops if a header cannot be found (and it **will** stop before trying to compile anything).

I believe that that is what you wanted?

Comment: You may be on to something here as well, but if you have noticed the many make files that make use of `--keep-going`, this will still spew a host of error messages and not quit at the first error. Still +1.

Answer (score 0):

you can write a shell script to check for error conditions before running the make script.